# Inform 7 error using If player consents

Tags: inform7

I'm trying to write a piece of interactive fiction using inform 7, I want to put a choice in there for the player and I want a simple yes or no I used the following code:

```
if the player consents say "You get a better view of the stranger."

Otherwise:
say "You can't make out what's happening clearly, however, you notice the stranger walking out of the pub"
```

I then get this useless error message:

You wrote 'if the player consents say "You get a better view of the stranger."'  : but I can't find a verb that I know how to deal with. This looks like an 'if' phrase which has slipped its moorings, so I am ignoring it. ('If' phrases, like all other such instructions, belong inside definitions of rules or phrases - not as sentences which have no context. Maybe a full stop or a skipped line was accidentally used instead of semicolon, so that you inadvertently ended the last rule early?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punctuation is off. Phrases should end with a semicolon, and if phrases should use either begin..end blocks, or the "colon-and-indentation" style. So either:

```
if the player consents begin;
say "You get a better view of the stranger.";
otherwise;
say "You can't make out what's happening clearly, however, you notice the stranger walking out of the pub";
end if;
```

or

```
    if the player consents:
        say "You get a better view of the stranger.";
    otherwise:
        say "You can't make out what's happening clearly, however, you notice the stranger walking out of the pub";
```

Note the colons and semicolons and tabs in the second example.

Also, as the error message says, you need to specify *when* that question should be asked. If phrases must be inside rules or phrases. For example, if the question should be asked as a result of an action:

```
After examining the stranger for the first time:
    say "Move closer?";
    if the player consents begin;
    say "You get a better view of the stranger.";
    otherwise;
    say "You can't make out what's happening clearly, however, you notice the stranger walking out of the pub";
    end if;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, exactly what I wanted.